# How to get best of three columns from five columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I have a table like below

```
ID     M1    M2    M3   M4  M5
121    3      5     6    8   4
122    5      2     1    9   6
```

For each row, I need to get the three columns with the maximum values, and the other values should be NULL.  For the table above, the output should be:

```
ID     M1    M2    M3   M4  M5
121          5     6    8   
122    5                9   6
```

Can anyone help me how to do it in Oracle or MySQL?

Comment: What is the logic behind it?

Comment: Why COlumn M4 has got 2 values?

Comment: What should happen for 2 2 2 2 2

Comment: What should happen for 2 2 2 3 2

Comment: What should happen for 2 1 2 2 2

Comment: Or are duplicate values in rows not allowed?

Comment: @user1844209 Why is the output of M4 has two values - 8 and 9?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get maximum value from the table you can use sub-query like this:

```
SELECT ID
,(CASE WHEN M1 = MM1 THEN M1 ELSE '' END) AS M1
,(CASE WHEN M2 = MM2 THEN M2 ELSE '' END) AS M2
,(CASE WHEN M3 = MM3 THEN M3 ELSE '' END) AS M3
,(CASE WHEN M4 = MM4 THEN M4 ELSE '' END) AS M4
,(CASE WHEN M5 = MM5 THEN M5 ELSE '' END) AS M5
FROM Table1
JOIN
(
SELECT MAX(M1) AS MM1
      ,MAX(M2) AS MM2
      ,MAX(M3) AS MM3
      ,MAX(M4) AS MM4
      ,MAX(M5) AS MM5
FROM Table1
) A
```

Output:

```
|  ID | M1 | M2 | M3 | M4 | M5 |
--------------------------------
| 121 |    |  5 |  6 |    |    |
| 122 |  5 |    |    |  9 |  6 |
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e0ae3/4)

Comment: I don't think this is what OP wanted, I think he wants the 3 highest columns/values for each record (as if `max(m1,m2,m3,m4,m5)`)

Answer (score 1):

Try this (aaabbb is the name I gave your table in the fiddle):

```
with p as (
select *
from aaabbb
unpivot
(
v for c in (m1,m2,m3,m4,m5)
)
), max_v as (
select p1.id,  max(p1.v) v1, max(p2.v) v2, max(p3.v) v3
from p p1 
join p p2 on p1.v > p2.v and  p1.id = p2.id
join p p3 on p2.v > p3.v and  p2.id = p3.id
group by p1.id) 
select ab.id, 
case when m1 in (mv.v1, mv.v2, mv.v3) then m1 end  m1,
case when m2 in (mv.v1, mv.v2, mv.v3) then m2 end  m2,
case when m3 in (mv.v1, mv.v2, mv.v3) then m3 end  m3,
case when m4 in (mv.v1, mv.v2, mv.v3) then m4 end  m4,
case when m5 in (mv.v1, mv.v2, mv.v3) then m5 end  m5
from aaabbb ab join max_v mv on ab.id = mv.id
```

results are:

```
ID     M1    M2    M3   M4  M5
121          5     6    8   
122    5                9   6
```

**[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f6904/1) is a sqlfiddle demo**

Comment: Don't know why but I expected [this](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQUOote3K5OljulGYK54tmRcYOGSRohU1-GNOFNsrshnVBzKumCLw)

Comment: @Rene, That's a good one! Edited my answer - changed from **fiddle** to **sqlfiddle demo**

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, no, neither with oracle less than 11g (though can be modified to)

Answer (score 0):

In oracle ::
 I am not sure about the certain rule you are trying to invoke here:

```
select id,
decode(m1,1,null,2,null,3,null,4,null,M1) M1,
decode(m2,1,null,2,null,3,null,4,null,M2) M2,
decode(m3,1,null,2,null,3,null,4,null,M3) M3,
decode(m4,1,null,2,null,3,null,4,null,M4) M4,
decode(m5,1,null,2,null,3,null,4,null,M5) M5
from tab order by id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query -

```
SELECT
  id,
  IF(t1.m1 = t2.m1, t1.m1, null) m1,
  IF(t1.m2 = t2.m2, t1.m2, null) m2,
  IF(t1.m3 = t2.m3, t1.m3, null) m3,
  IF(t1.m4 = t2.m4, t1.m4, null) m4,
  IF(t1.m5 = t2.m5, t1.m5, null) m5
FROM
  m_table t1,
  (SELECT
     MAX(m1) m1, MAX(m2) m2, MAX(m3) m3, MAX(m4) m4, MAX(m5) m5 FROM m_table
  ) t2
```